# Execute sql-statement once at date x

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to have an sql update-statement executed once at date x. How can I achieve this on an Oracle 10g database?

**EDIT:**
My aim is to fire an update statement every day. Why? I have a tiny mistake in my application, that can be 'temporarily fixed' with this statement (since I only have db-access till the real fix will happen).

Jonny

Comment: Do you mean where date is equal to something (select * from table where date = XX-XX-XX), otherwise would I do this in a scripting language, such as php. Its easier and you have better control in my mind than doing it straight SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to schedule a work to run at particular time using dbms\_scheduler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016842/how-to-schedule-a-work-to-run-at-particular-time-using-dbms-scheduler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider DBMS_SCHEDULER.  It is meant for running jobs periodically, but you can set up your pl/sql job script to suspend or cancel the job entry after your run-once job ends successfully.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse.htm

Comment: +1: DBMS_SCHEDULER is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Crontab to schedule a task to be executed at given day/time.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. unfortunately i don't have access on the machine itself. i only have rights on the database.